# The graphics of ubuntu 14.04 is slow

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

When I open a window or a video the Ubuntu and the video are very slow.

> RAM : 3 gb
>   Processor : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 3800+ × 2
>   Graphics  : GeForce 6150 LE/integrated/SSE2/3DNOW!
>   OS type : 32-bit

Comment: Ubuntu with Unity is too much for old Nvidia cards, try Xubuntu 14.04 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer doesn't have the best graphics anyway; dual core with 3 GB or RAM won't do much. If you want to have Ubuntu run perfectly, I suggest Xubuntu, which is made for computers like yours. Xubuntu is based on Ubuntu and should work with all your programs.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the graphics what are slow, you can also try with the proprietary Nvidia driver (which, as of now, is much faster than the open source one).

Or you can try an alternative Desktop Environment, such as XFCE (used by Xubuntu, and way faster than Unity/Gnome/KDE) or MATE.

Comment: Okay I will Try The proprietary Nvidia driver